# Keyword not supported: 'data source'

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

i am new for `Entity framework`.I just try code first mode.
I want insert data to my student table.

```
//this is the insert.cs code

public class Insertingvalue
{
     public Insertingvalue()
     {

     }

     public static void addvalue()
     {
         var newstudent=new Student();
         newstudent.student_id= 008;
         newstudent.student_name = "lakshmi";
         newstudent.class_name = "12th";
         newstudent.mark1 = 60;
         newstudent.mark2 = 70;
         newstudent.mark3 = 80;

         using (var dbcon=new Context())
         {
             //dbcon.Database.Connection.Open();
             dbcon.Students.Add(newstudent);
             dbcon.SaveChanges();
         }
     }
}
```

My connection string given below

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Context" 
             connectionString="Data Source=AFRESH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;
             Initial Catalog=laks;
             Integrated Security=True;
             App=EntityFramework" 
             providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

error is Keyword not supported: 'data source'.
i unable to fix this bug.pls help me

Comment: Where is this Connection String in your project?  The syntax looks correct if this is in your config file.

Comment: i used this connection in my project    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public Context() :
            base("name=Context")
        {

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
    
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
       
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is caused because of the incorrect providerName attribute, where you put System.Data.EntityClient but you should use **System.Data.SqlClient** if you would like to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server. For the most common providerName choices see this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.providername.aspx

After you change this property your code should work like a charm :)

Comment: You saved me a lot of time. Thanks.